# Series circuits and serial circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, series

I have seen quite a few times now where someone creates a simple circuit and when describing the configuration of the components they say that it is either in parallel or serial.

I have only ever heard of parallel and series, is the word serial a mistake or are components in series also called serial ?

Comment: [Series](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/series) is correct.

Comment: Series is correct. But even if misused it should be fairly obvious in context which one is being referred to. Like if I say I have a pair/pear...unless we're playing poker while I'm eating a pear.

Comment: You might pare a pear whilst being dealt a pair @DKNguyen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The resistors R1 and R2 are **connected in series**
2. The **serially connected resistors** R1 and R2, share the input voltage unequally
3. The current through the resistors are the same as they are **in series.**
4. **Serial and parallel connections sounds odd** compared to series and parallel LEDs
5. For communication protocol, **always serial** is used.. Serial WiFi, parallel port, Serial port etc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftENrW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits

Answer (score 3):

Typically components would be connected in **series** and a data protocol can be **serial**.